# How to set conditional property on component in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react date selector plugin called react-flatpickr. When I want the flatpickr to be disabled, I need to set a prop called "disabled" on the Flatpickr component. disabled is not a boolean that can be set to true or false. disabled is a property without a value. Is there a way to initialize the Flatpickr component with the disabled prop only when readOnly is true, instead of this horribly duplicated code?

```
getFlatPickr(id, ref, defaultDate, minDate, readOnly){
    if (readOnly) {
        return (
            <Flatpickr
                id={id}
                name={id}
                disabled
                className={"form-control"}
                placeholder={"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"}
                options={{
                    enableTime: true,
                    dateFormat: this.state.flatpickrDateFormat,
                }}
            />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Flatpickr
                id={id}
                name={id}
                className={"form-control"}
                placeholder={"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"}
                options={{
                    enableTime: true,
                    dateFormat: this.state.flatpickrDateFormat
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `disabled={readOnly}` ?

Comment: I have. The property is a single word - "disabled." It has no value, not true or false, so setting it to the value of readOnly does not work.

Comment: In react attributes passed without a value are assumed to be booleans and are given a `true` value.

Comment: If however you want the receiving component to not even register the prop then use `disabled={readonly || undefined}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, simply set the `disabled` prop directly to your `readOnly` variable :

```
getFlatPickr(id, ref, defaultDate, minDate, readOnly) {
        return (
            <Flatpickr
                id={id}
                name={id}
                disabled={readOnly}
                className={"form-control"}
                placeholder={"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"}
                options={{
                    enableTime: true,
                    dateFormat: this.state.flatpickrDateFormat
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Even shorter syntax :

```
getFlatPickr = (id, ref, defaultDate, minDate, readOnly) => (
    <Flatpickr
        id={id}
        name={id}
        disabled={readOnly}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"
        options={{
            enableTime: true,
            dateFormat: this.state.flatpickrDateFormat
        }}
    />
)
```